# Serial connection possibility between Windows and CentOs7

Tags: centos, windows, serial-port, serial-console

I want to establish connection via `putty` (serial connection) using UC232a adapter connected to null modem cable, connected to mini-serial-to-DB9 adapter and then to another PC with CentOS 7.

First of all I've got Windows 10 on machine with `putty`. Installed all necessary drivers to uc232 adapter. Selected right COM port number in `putty` (as its shows on device manager) but either way I can't even establish connection with my own COM port. Its shows only black screen. If I hit enter twice nothing happen.

I've also tried pin up two pins RXD and TXD and then console reacts to keyboard writing. Its shows chars. Why don't I get a login prompt?

From the other hand on CentOS 7 Ive enabled COM port on BIOS, also installed `minicom` and configured via `minicom -s`.

When I use `dmesg |grep tty` it prints that the console `tty0` enabled and shows ports from `ttyS0` to `ttyS3`.

Is any chance to comunicate between those two computers with different OS?

Comment: What do you get from centos if you run `ps -t ttyS0` ?  Did you set the baud rate on both ends?  If you run in centos `echo test > /dev/ttyS0` do you get anything in putty?

Comment: When I run 1st command I get: "PID TTY  TIME CMD". When I run echo, command lags for a while and nothing shows on Putty. Ive noticed that if I enter bios I get all things also on Putty, whats more I can controll it via Putty, but when I exit from bios and post OS boot menu appears and I choose which OS I want to boot display on Putty goes dark and again nothing happens. I assume is connected, but I didnt get why it doesnt work properly...

Comment: Baud rate on both is 115200(and it shows the CentOS BIOS on putty when device od starting).

Answer (score 0):

Serial is a very basic communications protocol and is operating system agnostic.  You should be able to use it to communicate between different operating systems, but you have to get all the details on both ends correct.

The bios POST is probably showing because the bios has serial console enabled.  However, once the operating system boots, the operating system takes over the serial port.  By default, it won't do anything with it unless you enable that.  Note that the bios sets the baud rate during POST, but you may have to separately set it in the operating system as well.

There are three ways to enable activity on the serial port from the operating system.

- Run an application (for example echo) on the port.  The delay and lack of results in putty indicate that either ttyS0 is the wrong port (try ttyS1?) or the port settings are preventing data from being sent, so you may need to experiment there.
- Tell linux to use the port as a console.  You can do this by adding `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200` to the grub command line (either live or permanently in the configuration -- I suggest doing it temporarily live until you know it works)
- Instead of setting the port as a console, you can use systemd to enable a getty on the port to provide a login prompt (without the noise of also being a console); Note, you should probably hard code the baud rate getty uses in the systemd configuration

Comment: echoing on ttyS0 is smooth, no delay but no response on putty terminal on mine Windows. Where I can get accessto grub command line? I've written this while booting on OS choosing - no results.

3rd point I didn't get :(

Comment: If you get no response on putty, you probably have the wrong serial port.  Try ttyS1 next.  Here's grub links, sorry for the ubuntu link, but half of those instructions work, and I can't find good instrudtions for both halves for centos in one place. https://askubuntu.com/questions/19486/how-do-i-add-a-kernel-boot-parameter  https://www.geekpills.com/operating-system/linux/how-to-change-edit-kernel-cmdline-in-centos7

Comment: OK, I've used 2nd link but while changing grub file in editor and rebuilding config file the changes aren't visible while performing 'cat /proc/cmdline' ... :/ But when I cat file it is...

Comment: Echoing on ttyS0 is not delayed, on other ports like ttyS1 ... ttyS3 gives a delay in console 
 In both ways no response in Putty window :/